# How to calculate distance scroll up and down recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I want to show and hide button when recyclerview scrolls up and down by some distance (Distnce height of button)I have written some code but its not working as expected

```
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(view, dx, dy);
    if (verticalOffset > floatingActionMenu.getHeight() && dy > 0) {
        floatingActionMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        floatingActionMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    verticalOffset += dy;
}
```

Comment: You want to show button if user is scrolling up and hide if user scrolling down side. Is this you want ?

Comment: yeah right that what I want

Comment: Have you got solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement onScrollStateChange as well.

My draft looks like this.

```
    int distance =0;
    int scrollDirection;

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        scrollDirection = dy;
        distance+=dy;
        Log.d("TAG", "onScrolled: " + dy);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            if (scrollDirection > 0) {
                Log.d("TAG", "onScrollStateChanged: " + " STOPPED " + distance);
                distance = 0;
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "onScrollStateChanged: " + " STOPPED " + distance);
                distance = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Depending on final `distance` value you get in `onScrollStateChange` you can deside, to hide your button or not. Should I tell, that you have to hide/show your FAB in `onScrollStateChanged` as well?